# Performing bash-like string manipulation in GNU parallel

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-parallel

I like GNU `parallel`, but I find performing string replacements rather complex.

I'm used to simple manipulation such as done in Bash:

```
$ f="encodes/TearsOfSteel-720-crf41.mp4"
$ echo "$(basename "${f%%-*}")"
TearsOfSteel
```

Basically, I want to find the basename (everything before the first minus-hyphen) of each input file. With `parallel`, I'd then want to perform a command with the original filename and the basename:

```
parallel './do_something {} <basename>' ::: encodes/*.mp4
```

… where `<basename>` is what Bash would do if you gave it `basename "${f%%-*}"`, and `f` obviously being `{}`.

The non-parallel version would be:

```
for f in encodes/*.mp4; do
  bn="$(basename "${f%%-*}")"
  ./do_something "$f" "$bn"
done
```

How can I do that with `parallel`?

Answer (score 3):

If you do that a lot define your own replacement string by putting this into `~/.parallel/config`:

```
--rpl '{_} s:.*/::; s:-.*::;'
```

Then you can do:

```
parallel ./do_something {} {_} ::: encodes/*.mp4
```

Also remember you can just define a `bash` function and call that:

```
doit() {
  f="$1"
  bn="$(basename "${f%%-*}")"
  ./do_something "$f" "$bn"
}
export -f doit
parallel doit {} ::: encodes/*.mp4
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found an easy way to do Bash-style manipulation, but you can use `perl` expressions to perform string replacements. It's simple enough to remove parts of the string you don't want, subsequently.

One way to do that would be:

```
parallel "./do_something {} {= s:.*\/::; s:-.*:: =}" ::: encodes/*.mp4
```

How does that work?

You [can run `perl` commands inside `parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Perl-expression-replacement-string) with `{= … =}`. With `perl`, you can remove the folder name with the expression:

```
s/.*\///
```

That means: replace everything up to the first slash with nothing. We can swap the delimiters from `/` to `:` to make it more readable (`s:.*\/::`).

You can do the same with the trailing part, i.e., removing everything from the first minus-hyphen onwards, which is:

```
s:-.*::
```

The whole command is a combination of these two replacements, separated by a semicolon. The command then becomes:

```
{= s:.*\/::; s:-.*:: =}
```

Comment: GNU Parallel replacement strings are already quoted, so adding ' around {=...=} may cause problems if the input has a '.